# Change a folder path for commit in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to modify folder structure (path) for pushed commits in Gitlab?
For example, my old path is *homework*, now I want to add a parent folder before that, i.e. *superfolder/homework*? Tks and welcome for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so while keeping the history of `homework`, you need to [install](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) the Python-based tool [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).

That tool has [a renaming based on paths option](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_renaming_based_on_paths_see_also_filename_callback)

In your case:

```
git filter-repo --path-rename homework:superfolder/homework
```

Note that it changes the history of the repository, which will have to be forced pushed (`git push --force`): not a big deal if you are the only one working on it.